# Зависание видео на сайте

Tags: html, html5, видео

На сайте добавлено видео, методами html5

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="auto" loop autoplay muted>
<source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4'></source>
<source src="video.webm" type='video/webm'></source>
</video>
```

видеофайл с расширением webm отлично работает, а вот mp4 через раз. Бывает зависает через 3-5 сек после старта, бывает останавливается после первого воспроизведения, хоть и стоит свойство loop, бывает 2-3 раза прокручивается и встает. И вторая проблема, chrome то воспроизводит первое по порядку видео (как должен), то играет второе. С чем это связано?
P.S. с кодеками баловался по всякому, не помогло.

Comment: От браузера, мощности компьютера и скорости интернета. Оно не может загрузить первое видео и по этому воспроизводит второе только

Comment: на вряд ли, ибо на такое натыкаюсь впервые (и как не смешно на своем проекте). Да и зависание видео в mp4 это не объясняет. И проверял данный момент на 2 разных машинах, с 2 разных провайдеров.